# Big-O notation check understanding

Tags: java, big-o

I want to check my understanding of Big-O notation. If I have code:

```
 for(int bound = 1; bound <= n; bound *= 2){
      for( int i = 0; i < bound; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < n; j += 2){
                   .....Code
            }
            for(int j = 1; j < n; j *= 2){
                   ......Code
            }
      }
 }
```

is the Big-O notation for this N<sup>3</sup>?

Comment: What do *you* think? Please share your thoughts.

Comment: "for(int j = 0; j < n; += 2){"   what is **+= 2** ? is it j += 2 ?

Comment: @markusmalkusch Indeed. After I asked him to.

Comment: I included it in the original post

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not quite. The outer loop increment is `bound *= 2`, so that loop is O(log n).  The two inner loops (`i` and the first `j` loop) are both O(n), so when nested they're O(n<sup>2</sup>). (You can ignore the `j *= 2` inner loop because it's faster than the `j += 2` loop and won't significantly contribute to the program's run time.)

Put this all together and the whole program is O(log n * n<sup>2</sup>).

Comment: I dont completely understand logs if bound *= 2 was bound /=2 would that also be a log

Comment: @user116484 If it was bound/=2 what would bound become after the 1st iteration? Answer: 0. So the outer-most loop would become an infinite loop.

Comment: @user116484 If `bound` started at `n` and the condition was `bound >= 1`, then yes, `bound /= 2` would also make that loop run in log time. Think of how many times the loop will run for different values of n. It won't run n times, but a much lower value, near the log of n.

Comment: You can see the `log n` performance with a simple test. Write the index out for each iteration: `for(int bound = 1; bound <= n; bound *= 2) { System.out.println(bound); }`.  Now try `n=10`, then `n=100`, and so on (increasing by a factor of 10).  You'll see the number of items output increases linearly while `n` increases by an order of magnitude.

Comment: half of bound. if bound was 4 it would become 2.